# django modelform showing an existing instance

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the following model:

```
ynChoice = ((None, 'Acknowledgement not required'),
            (True, 'Acknowledgement and consent required'),
            (False, 'Acknowledgement required but consent not required'))

class AbstractForm(models.Model):
    """base class for the below 2 classes"""
    #require users to say yes and no other than acknowledging #null = not required
    yes_no_required = models.NullBooleanField(choices=ynChoice, blank=False)
```

and I map it to my modelform:

```
class LiveConsentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ynChoice = (
                ('', '---------------'),
                (None, 'Acknowledgement not required'),
                (True, 'Acknowledgement and consent required'),
                (False, 'Acknowledgement required but consent not required'),
                )
    yes_no_required = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=ynChoice,empty_value='')
    class Meta:
        model = ConsentFormTemplate
```

Here, `ConsentFormTemplate` is a subclass of `AbstractForm`. I wrote `yes_no_required` in the form because the empty value for the nullbooleanfield's formfield will return a `None`, which I do not want.

Now, when I want instantiate my form to show an existing record, `LiveConsentForm(instance=templateInstance)`, I run into a problem.

My `templateInstance.yes_no_required`'s value is None, but when the html is rendered, `------` is selected. (I do not have such trouble when `yes_no_required` is either `True` or `False`)

Need some help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i've looked at the forms.fields and

turns out that when rendering to html, turns out that None is just treated as '', and empty_value is not taken into consideration here. I'm not sure why  @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams dude took away his answer, so if you can please put it back up again, i'll accept it.